# Salesforce Opportunities Object - Validation Rules - Make checkboxes mandatory to progress stage

Tags: validation-rule, opportunity, checkbox

This is my first time posting on the stack exchange so apologies if any key information is missing from my question.

I am trying to create a validation rule to make certain checkbox fields in the opportunity object mandatory but nothing I have found in online forums seems to be working.

I have 4 opportunity stages each with 2-5 checkboxes that I want to be required to be ticked before the stage is progressed.

Example: for the Stage to be moved from stage 1 to stage 2 all checkboxes within stage 1 section must be ticked.

My plan (following advice from the trailblazer forum) was to create a unique validation rule for each of the checkboxes required at each stage.

The formula I am currently using that doesn't work:

```
AND(
    NOT(Template_created__c),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Onboarding Stage 2"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Onboarding Stage 3"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Onboarding Stage 4"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Onboarding Completed")
    )
)
```

Once the above validation rule has been saved I am still able to progress the stage to all stages with the "template created" checkbox unchecked - no error message is appearing.

Thanks in advance for you assistance with this.

Comment: Do those values match the API names of the picklist values?

Comment: Also, is the validation rule active?

Comment: Hi Fred, apologies for getting back to you but the salesforce project was put on hold for a couple weeks.

Yes those are the API names of the picklist values and the validation rule was active at the time.

The rule did not seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You should campare value of checkbox with true or false.

AND(
checkboxOne__c = false,
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Qualification")
)

Try this example of validation rule. Works for me. On the screen below exaple of error is case if I choose Qualification stageName but don't check checkbox.

[image]

For better error explanation mb you should create few validation rules instead of one. But of course you can describe all conditions in one validation rule.

Comment: Hi @Artem,
I hope you are well and thanks for the swift response.
Your suggestion worked so thank you :) 

I am hesitant to build this out as I have about 4 stages each with 4-7 checkboxes at each stage so this methodology would lead to a very large number of validation rules. 

Is there a way to amend the formula:

 "AND(  Template_sent_to_client__c = false,  
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Onboarding Stage 2" ), "

to make the field mandatory for multiple stages? ("Onboarding Stage 3" , "Onboarding Stage 4" etc.)

Many thanks!